# adding JSON values based on keys comparison

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop

I would like to compare the values of keys in a JSON object before appending to the object, and if they are the same, add the values instead of appending.

I have:

```
 {"carset": {
          "location1": [
                      {"car": "volvo", "count": 5},
                      {"car": "mazda", "count": 7},
                      {"car": "toyota", "count": 10},
                     ]
             }
  }
```

and when i hit this in my for loop:

```
newcar = 'volvo';
newcount = 6;
cars[i] = ({car: newcar, count: newcount});
```

I'd like to notice that volvo is already in the json object, and just add the newcount to the existing count. Thanks!

Comment: http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/ ... your problem has nothing to do with JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare with all the items in the `location1` array  or you can restructure your JSON to make the comparison easier

```
json = {
 'carset' : {
    'location-cars' : {
      'volvo'  : 5,
      'mazda'  : 7,
      'toyota' : 10
    }
  }
}

function addCar(cars, car) {
  var theCar = cars[car];
   if ( theCar == undefined ) {
      cars[car] = 1;
   } else {
      cars[car] = theCar + 1;
   }
   return cars[car];
}

addCar(json.carset['location-cars'], 'volvo');
```

Comment: Thats for your help shyam. I restructured to the above. How do I do the compare and add now?

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkExists(carName) {
    for (var k in a.carset.location1) {
        if (a.carset.location1[k].car == carName) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```